# My Response from the database returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, mongoose, react-redux, react-state-management, react-context

I am working on a login page and trying to store my data in context. But i get response from the database as undefined.

I think i am doing something wrong. Help please

Here's my code snippet
"AUTH CONTEXT" (The auth Context file returns undefined as response)

```
import { signIn as signInApi } from '../apis'

const AuthContext = createContext()

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [token, setToken] = useState(localStorage.getItem('token'))
  const [user, setUser] = useState(localStorage.getItem('user'))
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

  const signIn = async (email, password, callback) => {
    setLoading(true)
 
    const res = await signInApi(email, password)
    console.log(res) 

  ......
 const value = {
    token,
    loading,
    signIn,
    signOut,
  }

}

export default AuthContext
```

APIS.JS (The API.js file below returns response data from the database)

```
import axios from 'axios'

export const signIn = async (email, password) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.post(
      `${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/auth/login`,
      {
        email,
        password,
      },
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      }
    )

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

LOGIN FILE

```
const auth = useContext(AuthContext)

 
  const handleLogin = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    auth.signIn(email, password, () => history.replace('/admin'))
  }
```

Comment: `signIn` in API.js doesn't return `res`

Answer (score -1):

you didnot return response from your signIn function in API.js file